# Why is ALTER TABLE used for changing AUTO_INCREMENT variable?

Tags: mysql, sql

With MySQL, when you want change the password, or character set, you can do it as following:

```
SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS = 'utf8';
```

But when you want to change the autoincrement variable of a table, you need a different syntax for that:

```
ALTER TABLE foobar AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

This makes me to wonder if it would be more consistent if it was as following:

```
SET AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Because some `SET` operations applies on the table. But I assume there must be some  reasons for this syntax choice. When looking in the documentation, I found the following:

> ALTER TABLE changes the structure of a table. For example, you can add
>   or delete columns, create or destroy indexes, change the type of
>   existing columns, or rename columns or the table itself. You can also
>   change characteristics such as the storage engine used for the table
>   or the table comment.

But with `SET` keyword you could also change the structure of the table, I assume? Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: The auto increment is a property of a table, so you need to alter the table. I fail to see how you think that setting it globally/for your connection would somehow be a good idea.

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` isn't a system/server level variable, it's a column attribute whereas `CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS` is a system/server level variable which is why you need to use the `ALTER TABLE` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `SET` syntax for variable assignment enables you to assign values to different types of variables that affect the operation of the server or clients:
>
> - System variables. See Section 6.1.4, “Server System Variables”. System variables also can be set at server startup, as described in Section 6.1.5, “Using System Variables”.
> - User-defined variables. See Section 10.4, “User-Defined Variables”.
> - Stored procedure and function parameters, and stored program local variables. See Section 14.6.4, “Variables in Stored Programs”.
>
> **Source:** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html

The `SET` is an operation for the whole server / database. You can't set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` with `SET` only for a specific table. The `AUTO_INCREMENT` information is stored on the table itself. It's not a global variable because some tables can have a `AUTO_INCREMENT=1` and others `AUTO_INCREMENT=[another-int-value]`.

> To start with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value other than 1, set that value with `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE`, like this: `ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;`
>
> **Source:** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 2):

With SET you change mysql variables that are not tied to a particular table.

If you want to change the auto_increment variable, you change it for a specific table. That's why you need to use the ALTER TABLE syntax.

Also, anything you set with create table can be updated with ALTER TABLE. auto_increment is set when you create a table. If you don't set it, it defaults to 1.